# Load Value from Input Element into Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I tried to get the values out of input elements into a Bootstrap Modal to confirm the data which was entered. Because the form isn't submitted i can't load them into php variables. Now i have no clue how to get the value from the input elements into the Modal.

reservation.php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['bestaetigung'])){
$datum = isset($_POST['datum']) ? $_POST['datum'] : "";
$von = isset($_POST['von']) ? $_POST['von'] : "";
$bis = isset($_POST['bis']) ? $_POST['bis'] : "";
$courts = isset($_POST['courts']) ? $_POST['courts'] : "";
$bemerkung = isset($_POST['bemerkung']) ? $_POST['bemerkung'] : "";
}
```

reservation.php html code:

```
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-md-9">Platz reservieren</h1>
            <a href="reservierung.php" style="height: 50%; margin: 1% 1% 0 0;" class="btn btn-secondary col-md-1">Leeren</a>
            <button id="loadmodalbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="height: 50%; margin: 1% 0 0 0;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservierungsbestaetigung" onclick="loadModalData()">Reservieren</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="filterOptions" class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="datum">Datum</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datum" name="datum" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($datum) ?>">
            </div>
            <div id="filterOptions" class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="von">Uhrzeit Von</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="von" name="von" step="900" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($von) ?>">
            </div>
            <div id="filterOptions" class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="bis">Uhrzeit Bis</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="bis" name="bis" step="900" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($bis) ?>">
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row" id="courts">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 1</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="courts[]" value="1" id="court1checkbox" hidden>
            <canvas id="court1" class="canvas" width="300" height="340" onclick="leftClickOnCourt1()"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 2</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="courts[]" value="2" id="court2checkbox" hidden>
            <canvas id="court2" class="canvas" width="300" height="340" onclick="leftClickOnCourt2()"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <h3>Platz 3</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="courts[]" value="3" id="court3checkbox" hidden>
            <canvas id="court3" class="canvas" width="300" height="340" onclick="leftClickOnCourt3()"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

        <!-- Reservierungsbestaetigung -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="reservierungsbestaetigung" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reservierungsbestätigung</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h6>Daten</h6>
                        <div id="reservationdata">
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']) ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Platz</th>
                                    <td><?php echo "DATA FROM INPUT" ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Datum</th>
                                    <td><?php echo "DATA FROM INPUT" ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Von</th>
                                    <td><?php echo "DATA FROM INPUT" ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Bis</th>
                                    <td><?php echo "DATA FROM INPUT" ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <label for="bemerkung">Bemerkung: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="bemerkung"  class="form-control" placeholder="Bemerkung" id="bemerkung">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="bestaetigung" onclick="platzReservieren()" value="Reservieren">Jetzt Reservieren</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You should use javascript scenario on client side.

Comment: And how do i do that? Can you please give me a short code example?